# oracle 12g invalid number error

Tags: sql, oracle

```
create table WeeklySaleReport
( ReportID varchar(20) primary key
, StartDate date
, EndDate date
, SaleAmount number (8,2)
, ComRate number (8,2)
, ComAmount number (8,2)
, EmployeeID int
, EName varchar(70)
, BrandID varchar(20)
, BName varchar(70)
, BSaleAmount number(8,2)
, TypeID varchar(20)
, TName varchar(20)
, TSaleAmount number(8,2)
, ESaleAmount number(8,2)
, EBonus number(8,2)
, DepartmentID references Department(DepartmentID) );
```

This table is made successfully

but when trying to insert these fields, it gives me error "Invalid Number":

```
insert into WeeklySaleReport
values
  ( 'R1', TO_DATE ('2018/06/16','yyyy/mm/dd')
  , TO_DATE ('2018/07/11','yyyy/mm/dd')
  , '9020.00', '2324.21', '20.00', 'E1'
  , 'Bassi', 'B1', 'Brand One', '123.00'
  , 'Type1', 'T One', '500.00', '123.00'
  , '555.00', 'D1' );
```

Comment: Blind insert is huge antipattern. You should always define column list. `EmployeeID int` -> `'E1'`. **[Working demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b1a0bee537f03bb1009eda78322019fb)**

Comment: locate the column that has the problem, then modify your question to show only the problematic column and the problematic inserted value.

Comment: As an aside, you should avoid using `VARCHAR` in Oracle - use `VARCHAR2` instead. It's possible that Oracle could change the behavior of `VARCHAR` in the future to meet the ANSI standard, and you don't want to be caught on the hop when that happens. Also, I would recommend using `NUMBER` instead of `INT`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would strongly advise that you write your inserts more like this:

```
insert into WeeklySaleReport (ReportID, StartDate, EndDate, SaleAmount, ComRate, ComAmount,
                              EmployeeID, EName, BrandID, BName, BSaleAmount,
                              TypeID, TName, TSaleAmount, ESaleAmount, EBonus)
     values 'R1',                   -- ReportID
             DATE '2018-06-16',     -- StartDate
             DATE '2018-07-11',     -- EndDate
             9020.00,               -- SaleAmount
             2324.21,               -- ComRate
             20.00,                 -- ComAmount
             'E1'                   -- EmployeeId
    ---------^ ERROR
             'Bassi',               -- EName
             'B1',                  -- BrandId
             'Brand One',           -- BName
             123.00,                -- BSaleAmount
             'Type1',               -- TypeId
             'T One',               -- TName
             500.00,                -- TSaleAmount
             123.00,                -- ESaleAmount
             555.00,                -- Bonus
             'D1'                   -- DepartmentId
            );
```

Notes:

- List the columns in the update.  Here, I've also added them as comments so you and others can follow what is going where.
- `EmployeeId` is obviously an error.
- Oracle recommends using `VARCHAR2()` rather than `VARCHAR()` for strings.
- Know your types!  Don't put single quotes around numeric constants.  It is misleading.
- Use the `DATE` keyword.  It is ANSI standard and easier to read.

And I just learned something.  The `DepartmentId` declaration *is* valid in Oracle, even though it does not have a type.  [Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fd969) is a SQL Fiddle.  Most databases require the type definition in the table.  However, I still don't know if the value is valid, because the type is not clear in the question.

Answer (score 3):

You have defined `EmployeeID int` in your table, then you try to insert the value `'E1'` into that column.